# Is there a way to change this closure to an async one?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have services with trait like:

```rust
#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait ServiceOne: Send + Sync {
    async fn player_update(
        &self,
        id: &str,
        lambda: &(dyn Fn(Player) -> Result<Player> + Sync),
    ) -> Result<Player>;
}
```

which I use like this:

```rust
pub struct UpdateHandler {
    service_1: Arc<dyn ServiceOne>,
    service_2: Arc<dyn ServiceTwo>,
    service_3: Arc<dyn ServiceThree>,
}

impl UpdateHandler {
    pub fn new(
      service_1: Arc<dyn ServiceOne>,
      service_2: Arc<dyn ServiceTwo>,
      service_3: Arc<dyn ServiceThree>,
    ) -> Self {
      Self { service_1, service_2, service_3 }
    }

    pub async fn handle(&self, input: PlayerInput) -> Result<Player> {
        let output = self.service_1.player_update(&input.id, & |player_from_db| {
            // this closure is a DB transaction; if something fails in here everything is rolled back

            let new_player = Player::update(player_from_db, input)?;

            self.service_2.player_update(&input.id, &new_player).await?;
            
            self.service_3.player_update(&input.id, &new_player).await?;

            Ok(new_player)
        })
        .await?;

        Ok(output)
    }
}
```

I would like to know if and how to transform that closure (called `lambda`) in an **async** one, because as you can see I need to call `.await` many times in that closure.

If it's not possible is there another way to organize my code? (Among other things I also think that my `lambda` definition is not totally efficient and idiomatic; by the way, do you have hints?).

I need to call those methods in the closure because that closure is a database transaction: if any service call fails that transaction is rolled back.

If there is NO way to have async closures with STABLE Rust, is there a way with UNSTABLE, nightly Rust using some feature flags?

**UPDATE**:

I created a reproduction here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e452166231a1eca70f45664dd85906a.

Can you help me understand what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the closure itself to be async, it just needs to return a future. This can be done by returning a `Box::pin(async { ... })`, and declaring the closure to have type:

```rust
lambda: &(dyn Fn(Player) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player>> + '_>> + Sync)
```

```rust
pub async fn handle(&self, input: PlayerInput) -> Result<Player> {
    let output = self
        .service_1
        .player_update(&input.id, &|player_from_db| {
            Box::pin(async {
                // this closure is a DB transaction; if something fails in here everything is rolled back

                let new_player = Player::update(player_from_db, input)?;

                self.service_2.player_update(&input.id, &new_player).await?;

                self.service_3.player_update(&input.id, &new_player).await?;

                Ok(new_player)
            })
        })
        .await?;

    Ok(output)
}
```

Comment: The compiler throws telling me I need to be in an async function to call await… can you show how to use this code?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman why is the life time `'_` needed in `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player>> + '_>> + Sync)`

Comment: I'm having issue with your code, @Chayim Friedman, rustc throws with: `error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier`, `^^ expected named lifetime parameter`, `help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from`, `note: these named lifetimes are available to use`. Why?

Comment: What is working right now is: `lambda: &(dyn Fn(DomainIdentity) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<DomainIdentity>> + Sync + Send>> + Sync)`. Is there a way to synthesize this? To reduce this boilerplate?

Comment: Another issue now is for `input`: `input does not live long enough, borrowed value does not live long enough`. Wow this is tragic.

Comment: I created a reproduction here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e452166231a1eca70f45664dd85906a. Can you help me understand what's the problem?